# How to find sub-vectors with same length from a vector in R?

Tags: r

How to find sub-vectors with same length  from a vector in R?

Comment: Perhaps you can check `?sample` and `?max`

Comment: If a sub-vector means consecutive elements of length k, then `library(zoo); rollmax(x, k)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first answer in this post to [R-Help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Splitting-a-vector-td4681930.html) to split the vector into vectors of equal length. In the code that follows `L` is the desired length of the sub-vectors.

```
X <- 1:12
L <- 3
sub_vec <- split(X, as.numeric(gl(length(X), L, length(X))))
```

Then use the `*apply` family of functions to do what you need with those sub-vectors. For instance, to compute the maxima:

```
sapply(sub_vec, max)
```

Comment: Is it possible through for loop?

Comment: @sandeep Why? There is no need for that. Besides, `sapply` *is* a loop.